# iOS 7 UITableViewCell with UITextView is hiding behind keyboard

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, ios7

So I'm having a little issue in iOS 7 with something that was working pretty much fine in iOS 6 (I know this get's said a lot but this one is just weird). So anyways, I have a Storyboard App and the TableView has some Prototype cells, one section has several labels and then a TextView for entering a response. Now in iOS6 when a user would click on the TextView the table would scroll to make room for the TextView to be seen above the keyboard, but now in iOS 6 (and only on the 4s iphone since it has the smaller screen) the keyboard slides up and the TableView only slides enough so that the whole TableViewCell is still visible which makes the TextView halfway behind the keyboard. This becomes troublesome because after typing in a single line of text the user has no idea of what else is being entered since the TextView is blocked by the keyboard. This is even worse on the first cell of the section since the TableView scrolls only enough to make the Cell and Header visible. I don't know if seeing the code would help but I'll post it below (also by default the Cell is is only tall enough to display the labels and then when the user clicks on a cell the height is expanded on that cell to reveal the TextView and Buttons below the labels)

```
if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
        if ([btrArray count] > 0) {
            BTRCustomCell *btrCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BTRCell"];



            //Check if BTR Row has been selected to expand View
            if (row == btrSelectedRow) {
                CGRect extended = btrCell.reasonLbl.frame;
                extended.size.height = 70;
                btrCell.reasonLbl.frame = extended;
                btrCell.responseTV.hidden = NO;
                btrCell.ackButton.hidden = NO;
                btrCell.replyButton.hidden = NO;
            }
            else {
                CGRect normal = btrCell.reasonLbl.frame;
                normal.size.height = 30;
                btrCell.reasonLbl.frame = normal;
                btrCell.responseTV.hidden = YES;
                btrCell.ackButton.hidden = YES;
                btrCell.replyButton.hidden = YES;
            }

//leaving out the lines that just add text to labels
btrCell.responseTV.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [[btrCell.responseTV layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
            [[btrCell.responseTV layer] setBorderWidth:2.3];
            [[btrCell.responseTV layer] setCornerRadius:15];
            btrCell.responseTV.tag = kBTRTextView + row;
            btrCell.responseTV.delegate = self;

            //Add Keybar to TextView
            UIToolbar *keyBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
            [keyBar setTintColor:MobileThemeColor];
            [keyBar sizeToFit];

            UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
            UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard:)];
            doneButton.tag = kBTRDoneButton + row;
            NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton, doneButton, nil];
            [keyBar setItems:itemArray];

            [btrCell.responseTV setInputAccessoryView:keyBar];

            //Add Targets To Buttons
            [btrCell.ackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(AcknowledgeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            btrCell.ackButton.tag = kBTRAckButton + row;
            [btrCell.replyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ReplyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            btrCell.replyButton.tag = kBTRReplyButton + row;

            return btrCell;
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix this or what is causing it. I'm pretty much re-writing the app since the original was built back for iOS3 and then just minor updates were made to support iOS6, so ARC wasn't being used and neither was Storyboards and Auto-Layouts which are pretty much a better way of working with an app and so this code was copied over right from the previous version to this one, but like I said it was pretty much working fine prior to iOS7. I don't know if it's just part of the new behavior in iOS7 that's not scrolling the TableView all the way up to view the TextView or something I did wrong in the setup so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

1) in .h file ,  `@interface MyViewController () <UITextViewDelegate>`

2) `yourTextView.delegate = self;`

3) Use this delegate method to scroll tableview up

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    if ([textView isEqual:yourTextView]) 
    {

        [tableview_WardList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathOfCellContainigTextview atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    }

}
```

when ever the editing of textview starts, the table will be scrolled up. Be sure to pass the indexpath of cell which contains the textview.